# Show.net controls on vb6 with full events

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I need to put a .net control on my vb6 form, i tried that but i have problem, not all events are handled.

I used Microsoft Forms Interop Toolkit.

Comment: Are you using an intermediate control?

Comment: Yes, i dont know how to make without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an intermediate control you need to wrap all events, or you just had acess to the events of UserControl class.
If not, maybe are not supported on vb6.

Comment: I will check it

Comment: Yeah, you are right... i need to wrap the events :(